# xCode iOS Dev - Apple Mach-O Linker Error // Dsymutil Error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mach-o, dsymutil

I'm in SERIOUS need of help.  I have had 3 unsuccessful evenings of unproductive coding.  Please someone, figure this error out & make me feel stupid for overlooking something so simple. :)

---

[ISSUE #1]

I keep getting the "**Apple Mach-O Linker Error**"
**Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

---

[ISSUE #2]

Also... I keep getting the "**Dsymutil Error**"
**error: unable to open executable '/Users/PsychodelicFuzz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CHH-bmbqxvfwddzaupfaavvipxaqwvfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CHH.app/CHH'**

---

Thanks to anyone willing to lend a helping hand <3

Comment: I don't remember where, but in your xcode you should be able to set the linker '-v' option and then check your output.....

Comment: does anyone else care to go into more detail?
I can't seem to find what I'm looking for (if it is the **linker'-v'** option) ??  Help Plz & Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can attach a printscreen of that error. It will give us more information to work with.

Comment: how can i add an image? is there a preferred uploader for this particular site? (stackoverflow) i've got the images ready to post :)

Answer (score 3):

Change Debug Information Format from build setting to  "DWARF"

Answer (score 0):

These are likely related.  `dsymutil` is getting an error because your executable binary `CHH.app` doesn't exist.  It doesn't exist because `ld` failed.

Open the Log Navigator pane in Xcode, click on your build entry in that pane after the build has failed, then if you hover over the right-hand side of the line for "`Link ... CHH.app`" you'll see a disclosure icon - hit that and you will see the actual `ld` invocation and the actual error message that it printed.  With luck that will get you pointed in the right direction.